# jQuery Conflict to my jquery code

Tags: jquery, conflict

I use a jQuery link to my mvc project after that I write jQuery code myself to my project. When I run it, it does not work but when I delete that link of jQuery to my project it works fine.

How can I fix this problem?

```
$(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    $("#sha").change(function () {
         var shaId = $(this).val();

         $.ajax(
                  { url: "/State/GetStates",
                    data: { shaId: shaId },
                    success: function (value) 
                             { cities = JSON.parse(value);
                               $("#shb").html("");
                               $("#shb").append("  <option>--- Please select ---</option>")

                               $.each(cities, function (idx, city) {
                                    $("#shb").append("<option value='" + city.Id + "'>" + city.name + "</option>")
                               })
                             }
                  })
             })
      });
```

Comment: Please include your code structure here

Comment: Please remove your comment and add the full code in your question above..including how your adding `jQuery`.

Comment: no  i mean to remove your comment...and put it in your Question

Answer (score -1):

it seems like your jquery is conflicting . visit this site it may help you out. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/